# FHIR-Server-for-Azure deployment

Tags: azure, hl7-fhir, fhir-server-for-azure

I am setting up a new open source FHIR Server (https://github.com/Microsoft/fhir-server) in Azure portal(1 month free subscription) as following the documents mentioned in the url . After deploying, I can retrieve the metadata of the service. But I have security issues to access the api's.

I don't have the Azure AD setup.So can some one guide me how to setup the FHIR server in Azure with out authorization/authentication?

Answer (score 2):

Set the `FhirServer:Security:Enabled` to `false` and Authentication/Authorization will be disabled.